# jQuery ajax request error callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm testing the error callback on a jQuery ajax request and I've got a question. Below is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'non-existant-file.php',
    data: { newFile : $('#name').val() },
    beforeSend: function() {
        // make nice image to show the request is running
    },
    success: function() {
        // show results of successfull request
    },
    error: function(jq,status,message) {
        alert('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message);
    }
});
```

The file does not exist, for the sole purpose of testing the error that is thrown. I would expect that it returns a 404 as status, and 'File not found' as message. Atleast, that's how I understand it when I read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.

But, the alert I get is nothing like what I expected:

```
A jQuery error has occurred. Status: error - Message: undefined
```

Am I understanding the docs wrong or am I just not doing it right?

Comment: Do you have an error page in your application in case the url doesn't exist?

Comment: Like a default 404 page? Then no. I don't. In the chrome error console it just throws 'GET http://localhost/km/admin/createFile.php?newFile= 404 (Not Found)' which I would have thought is the way that the ajax error would be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has to do with how your routing server responds to accessing a route that does not exist. JSFiddle, for instance, will return a slightly more helpful message: http://jsfiddle.net/dxSma/

Comment: This seems to be the most accurate answer. I did not know this, and, it is not what I expected. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following for error handling with jQuery AJAX:

```
error       : function( xhr ) {
    var readyState = {
        1: "Loading",
        2: "Loaded",
        3: "Interactive",
        4: "Complete"
    };
    if(xhr.readyState !== 0 && xhr.status !== 0 && xhr.responseText !== undefined) {
        alert("readyState: " + readyState[xhr.readyState] + "\n status: " + xhr.status + "\n\n responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

Maybe this can give you a couple of hints on how to get it to work properly.

Comment: It does give more info, and is better structured, but it returns what looks like a page. http://jsfiddle.net/dxSma/1/ Why make it sound spectacular when all the work still needs to be done yourself?

Comment: @DarkRanger It was not my intention to make it sound *spectacular*, this error function works great with ASP.NET WebServices atleast - with correct responseText.

Comment: I know it was not your intention. What I meant was, why did the developers behind jQuery add an error callback and in the docs, make it sound like everything you'll ever need, without it being what it's made up to be? It's nothing against you! :P It's more a million dollar question.

Comment: @DarkRanger That, sadly, I do not have an answer to. It might very well be dependant on what backend you're using.

Answer (score 0):

you can also work with the "Global Ajax Event Handlers"

.ajaxError() I am here show you the example and more you can find on this link.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Show a message when an Ajax request fails.

```
jQuery("#msg").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings){
  jQuery(this).append("<li>Error requesting page " + settings.url + "</li>");
});
```

or you can also work it like that an OLD way :)

```
jQuery.ajax({
 ...,
complete: function(e, XHR, options) {
  if (XHR.status == 200) { // success
  } elseif (XHR.status == 500) { // Internal Server Error
  } elseif (XHR.status == 404) { // File Not found
 }
});
```

Comment: wouldn't the second part me the same as saying:
`error: function (xhr) {
    alert(xhr.url + " could not be found.");
}` for example?

Comment: yes butyou can type custom messages for particular error code so it will be more feasible I suppose try it and let me know.